# Problem with Visual Studio 2022 Community edition

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I can't use Visual Studio, when I open it asks me to sign in with my account, and then nothing happens, I started facing this problem when I moved the program files and used it on my new laptop.

[image]

Comment: Why does it say "License: Prerelease software"? Have you tried updating VS (17.8 was released yesterday.)

Comment: Don't use pre-release versions of VS when you need to get your job done.  Run the installer to update.